# What is right place to start a WorkManager in MVVM architecture Android?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager, android-mvvm

I have a **workmanager** that every five hours picks up a word from the roomdb and **Notification** it

I do not know where is the righ place to put the work manager in the MVVM architecture.
Should I use in ViewModel or Repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the workmanager you only have `worker` classes, so you need to create a new package named `workers` or `workmanager` and place your workers in that package.

Comment: in Worker  to get data and notification it , Do I have to request  to the repository directly or use ViewModel ?

Comment: you can't use viewmodel in worker, you need to add your repository to the worker and use it.

Comment: @MoCoding I think the question is where we should start worker class, directly inside of 
a viewmodel or inside of a repository

Answer (score 1):

I think under datastore package or di package or make one work manager package and finally, work manager class can be used in ApplicationModule under di package,

Comment: in Worker  to get data and notification it , Do I have to request  to the repository directly or use ViewModel ?

Comment: By using ViewModel, we can request access for work manager.